# Using Sub-Modules that implement their own components

Tags: angular, typescript

So right now I am importing a whole bunch of individual components in `app.module` to cover all the things I need to use.

```
AppModule
    -Header Component
    -Header Sub-Component 1
    -Header Sub-Component 2
    -Header Sub-Component 3
```

What I would ideally like to do is rather than import them all in the `app.module`, I would like to create a `header.module` that handles importing all of its own components so that the `app.module` only needs to import the `header.module` and the `header.module` handles its own dependencies.

I've tried so many ways of doing this, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  What does the structure need to be?

I was trying to just do:

```
import { HeaderModule } from "./header/header.module";
```

In `AppModule`, and then have a `HeaderModule` that looked like:

```
// Core
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Components
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { ButlerBarComponent } from './butler/butler.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent
    ],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [ButlerBarComponent]
})

export class HeaderModule { }
```

Just to try to get the module > component relationship set up, but when I do this the declaration that calls the header component in `app.component.html` no longer has access to the `header` selector.

What do I need to do to make this work so I can put the `<header></header>` tag in `app.component.html` and have the application load `header.module` and the subsequent `header.component` and make the `header` selector available to `app.component.html`?

Comment: Can you show us what the `header.module` file looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare all those components in your `HeaderModule` and then export them so `AppModule` can access them when you import `HeaderModule` in `AppModule`. Also, you should import `BrowserModule` only in `AppModule`, in your other modules you should import `CommonModule` instead because it contains common directives such as `ngIf`, `ngFor`, `ngClass` etc. Finally, you don't need bootstrap here because you only bootstrap one component in your app and you do it in `AppModule`. So, your `HeaderModule` should look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HeaderComponent } from "./header.component";
import { ButlerBarComponent } from './butler/butler.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        HeaderComponent,
        ButlerBarComponent
    ]
})

export class HeaderModule { }
```

Now you only need to add `HeaderModule` to your `AppModule`'s imports and you should be ready to go.

Comment: I get the error `platform-browser has no exported member CommonModule`.

Comment: @StephenRios Yeah, it's located in `@angular/common`, not in `@angular/platform-browser`. I overlooked that, edited my post now.